Handling a very informative feature with significant missing values
I have a machine learning model where the goal is prediction in the context of regression.
For my metric of interest, there is a feature which is extremely informative but has significant missing values. Computing the metric using just a simple transformation of this feature alone gives very good results, so incorporating it into the model gives great results.
However this feature is only available for recent observations within the last month, and the dataset goes back several years. This feature has close to 98% missing values, but it is not missing at random - it simply wasn't collected prior to the last month.
What would be some ideas on how to handle this setting?
I am debating between training with the feature using only the one month of data, or excluding the feature and using the full (much larger) dataset. But these feel like two extremes and there should be a better way to incorporate both sources of information.
Edit: To simplify the setting, let's suppose the missing feature is $Z = Y + \epsilon$ so we can think of it as a noisy version of the outcome. Including $Z$ in the model would of course be very useful for predicting $Y$, but we only observe $Z$ for about 2% of the dataset.
The literature on semi-supervised learning allows for missing labels and suggests ways to incorporate this data to improve the performance of downstream supervised learning tasks. Is there a way to use a similar logic but in the case of a missing key feature?

Any particular flavor of ML model?

Mostly working with neural networks

Indeed even in regression methods, this is a classic case of dealing with an informative but missing-not-at-random (MNAR) feature in a regression setting. The key challenge is to balance the richness of the full dataset with the informativeness of the feature available in the recent subset as you rightly intuited. Also since the feature is MNAR, standard imputation methods might not work well.
If the feature is difficult to predict accurately from other features before the recent month, you can simply add a binary indicator variable for the feature that is missing before recent month. Then train the neural network using this indicator alongside the other features with the full dataset including the recent month, allowing the network to learn the relationship between the missing feature and the target. The binary indicator is computationally simple to implement and doesn’t require a separate imputation model. For neural networks, this can be an advantage, especially when you're dealing with large datasets and want to avoid adding complexity. In some cases, the missingness pattern is itself informative such as your described case, and using an indicator variable ensures that the model considers this information.
If above method doesn't perform well, you can try fine tuning a pretrained model. Use the full dataset excluding recent month to pretrain a NN model with the remaining features which learns general relationships between the features and the target without leveraging the missing feature. Then you'll use the model's learned parameters and fine-tune it with the recent month data after adding back the informative missing feature in input layer. Also note that fine-tuning should often use a lower learning rate than the pretraining phase, as you want to make subtle adjustments to the already learned weights.

Based on OP's latest edit, if the missing value is assumed to be always a noisy version of the label, you can use the recent month dataset to train a model to essentially predict the missing feature using other available features since now you have a good known imputation model which effectively transfers knowledge from the recent data to the historical data.

How do you know the missingness here is not at random? Why do you think the missingness pattern itself is informative here?

You missingness has a pattern as they're all in previous months dataset, not some random systemic error like MAR/MCAR. So it's a informative signal! The binary indicator feature captures this signal, which could itself be informative about the relationship between the feature and the target since your own observation confirms this feature alone once not missing gives good result. And my two-stage training approach helps the model adapt without overfitting on the sparse recent data, otherwise you can simply discard the previous full data which doesn't sound a good choice. Hope it clarifies now.

For random missingness like MCAR/MAR you can have unbiased imputation model, but for not-random NMAR cases in general you cannot have unbiased imputation since you can overfit your imputation model based on only recent month data. Of course once you assume a good imputation model in your edit, then you can impute. If you want to use semi-supervised learning idea, you can treat your imputation constraint as a regularization term in your loss function, so you can train it based on the full dataset including recent month, and when the missing feature is available regularization is applied.

Thanks! I especially like the idea of pre-training on the historical dataset excluding the key feature, then fine-tuning on the recent month with the feature. This seems very much in the spirit of semi-supervised learning.

Using the recent data to impute the key feature in the historical data is definitely worth trying too, though I'm somewhat concerned about the relative data sizes (since we are using 2% of the data to impute 98% of the missing features in the historical data, then training on the whole dataset). If we assume $Z = Y + \epsilon$, this idea makes me think of training a bijective NN by modeling $Z = f(Y|X)$, and $Y = g(Z|X)$ where $f,g$ are inverses conditional on $X$.

The bijective NN's nature ensures that the imputed values of Z remain consistent with the overall relationship between Z and Y, thus reducing bias. You can certainly try your bijective NN idea after the previous two, since you still have ample time before enough future months test data to arrive for this bijective NN's performance evaluation.
